# Alias a new name for a function (C)

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, alias, typedef

I've been trying to implement queue structure in C, using another implementation of linked list in C.

Some functions that I need for the queue are already defined in the linked_list.h, and I wanted to alias a new name for them; for example, to alias create_queue() for create_list().

Since I'm fairly new to C programming, I looked up online for a way to do this, and I ran into the topic of function pointers. It seemed like the right way to do what I wanted, yet when I tried it:

```
#include "linked_list.h"

typedef list_t queue_t; // list_t is the list type defined in linked_list.h,
                        // as well as the functions such as create_list()

queue_t (*create_queue)() = NULL; // Setting the function pointer to NULL
create_queue = &create_list; // Aliasing create_queue() for create_list()
```

When I try to compile, I get an error and a warning:

- **Error:** Redefinition of 'create_queue' with a different type: 'int' vs 'queue_t (*)()'
- **Warning:** Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'

What am I missing in my code? I don't want the full solution to my problem, just a redirection to the right way.

---

This is create_list():

```
list_t create_list(){
/* Creates and returns a NULL list, with index and value zeroed */
list_t list;
malloc(sizeof(list_t));

list.global_index = 0; /* Global index to keep how many nodes in the list, since no loops are allowed */
list.total_value = 0; /* Total value to keep total value of nodes in the list, since no loops are allowed */
list.head = NULL;
list.last = NULL;

return list;
}
```

And the struct definitions:

```
struct int_node {
int value;
struct int_node * previous; /* Needed to go to previous nodes with no loops */
struct int_node * next;
};

struct int_list {
int global_index;
int total_value;
struct int_node * head;
struct int_node * last;
};

/* Typedefs */
typedef struct int_node node_t;
typedef struct int_list list_t;
```

Comment: Please give the prototypes and the lines of your errors

Comment: I added the create_list() prototype. The error and the warning are both on the same line of:
    create_queue = &create_list;

Comment: Can you show the `list_t` structure aswell ?

Comment: can you show the line where compiler warns you?

Comment: @Ilay It's the same line as the error: create_queue = &create_list;

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace those lines:

```
queue_t (*create_queue)() = NULL; // Setting the function pointer to NULL
create_queue = &create_list; // Aliasing create_queue() for create_list()
```

with this line:

```
queue_t (*create_queue)() = &create_list; // Aliasing create_queue() for create_list()
```

I had this compiling without errors.

Comment: @MatanAbudy You cannot have statements outside functions, only declarations and initializers. The first one will work if you move the assignment into `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to create function wrappers, if the same function exists in the linked list. For example if you have

```
void linklist_add (int x);
```

and want to make a queue_add function, you'd implement it as:

```
void queue_add (int x)
{
  linklist_add(x);
};
```

Any type conversion from "`linklist_t`" to "`queue_t`" etc can be handled internally in the wrapper function.

Now upon reading this, at least ten people will immediately start to scream about extra function calling overhead. *Do not worry about this!* The compiler is likely able to optimize or inline the function. And even if it doesn't, the extra function calling overhead is neglectable on 99% of all systems out there.

Strive to make your code as readable as possible, this should always be the main concern. The simple solution is often the best solution. Optimization is something you should only consider when the actual need arises.

The function pointer works, but it would have to be a global variable, which is rarely a good idea. Also, function pointers tend to generate unreadable code, especially when you don't typedef them. Function pointers should be used for generic programming, not for caller interfaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I have two questions:
 1. What's the difference in readability between calling a function wrapper and calling a function pointer? It seems pretty much the same to me.
 2. Why the function pointer would have to be a global variable?

Comment: @MatanAbudy First of all there is C programmer de facto industry standard. When given an ADT such as your queue, you expect a list of functions present in a h file. You are not expected to fiddle around with global variables or internals of the ADT, that would be very bad program design. The function pointer would have to be a global variable or else the caller won't have access to it. And if you give a C programmer a list of global function pointers as their interface to your ADT, they will get very confused.

Comment: @MatanAbudy Also there is the private encapsulation concern. If your function pointers are not constant pointers, the caller could make them point elsewhere, either intentionally because they are mad, or by mistake.